# Adding a new dependency to pom does not work in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am having an issue while adding a new dependency to my pom.xml. I have an existing Maven project in eclipse. I added a new dependency to my pom.xml as follows:

```
 <dependency>
 <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
 <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
 <version>1.4.1</version>
 </dependency>
```

After that I right clicked on the project --> Maven -->Update project. However, there is a compilation error for the class for the following line:

```
private  JavaMailSender  mailSender;
```

The JavaMailSender is not found. Any idea what might be the issue?

Comment: Did you check whether library got downloaded in your local repository?

Comment: Can you do a Project ->Clean and also set enable the Build Automatically option in your eclipse. Also check whether the lib is avail in your repo.

Comment: Please include the `import` line for `JavaMailSender`. I suppose that you are using that one from `org.springframework` and that you need to add a new dependency in **pom.xml**.

Comment: have you import that package in code ? like import javax.mail ...

Comment: The library is downloaded and available in the repository. Also, the import statement is added.

Comment: rebuilding the project might solve then

Answer (score 1):

You could try to do right click on the `project > Maven > Update project` and check "`Force update of Snapshots/Releases`"

Or you can force to download the dependencies from terminal with the following command:

```
mvn clean install -U
```

Comment: I think force update would be similar to deleting everything in the repository right? I tried that and that didnt help either

Comment: nop, when you use the goal -U, maven check all snapshots in the remote repository and update your local repository if it’s out of date. You could try to delete the folder version `1.4.1` from your local repository ({local_repo}/javax/mail/mail/1.4.1) and run again `mvn clean install`. If you want to delete the dependencencies from your local repository, you could try to purge with the following command: `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository`, for more details: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/purging-local-repository.html

Comment: Thanks, that was useful. My problem got resolved, I was trying a couple of things simultaneously, so not sure what exactly solved the issue. But thanks for the detailed clarification.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the dependency, then compile it.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
<version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This in no way answers the question.

Comment: Why? The mail sender also requires the dependency I posted and the OP may not have included it.